# Magento links not working

Tags: magento

I migrated my website from one server to another. I am able to visit the home page on main website(eyaas.com), but other then that no links are working, not even the admin

Strangely, the indian version website(eyaas.com/in) is running fine with all links working properly.

When i migrated, I was seeing a 500 error so the hosting provider asked me to delete the .htaccess file which was auto-created simultaneously. Then the site worked but now this problem has arised.

What should i do. When replace the .htaccess file with the earlier one, I get a 500 server error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.hatccess` file is necessary for the rewrites. Speak with your hosts and make sure that it is configured properly for Magento.

Comment: they have set the .htaccess file and site is working. But now i am unable to login into admin section. After entering username and pass, it redirects to the same page without any error :(

Comment: Ya i understand that. I have raised the support ticket telling that i am unable to login into admin section.

Comment: That's probably the best solution :)

Comment: I usually do this the next day. This makes sure that more users visits the question. Not, only it helps me, but it also helps the answerer to get more points